# How can I merge 2 rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to retrieve value from multiple. The problem is in Table A there's a boolean type (isLocked) and  I have to create a column for each state ('Locked' and 'Unlocked'). Here's the query that I wrote:

```
SELECT    Machine.Machine_ID,
SUM(FinanceDonnee.CoutHoraire) AS Total,
CASE 
WHEN FinanceDonnee_isLocked = 1
 THEN
    SUM(FinanceDonnee.CoutHoraire)
 ELSE
    0
END
AS Locked,
CASE 
WHEN FinanceDonnee_isLocked= 0
 THEN
    SUM(FinanceDonnee.CoutHoraire)
 ELSE
    0
END
AS Unlocked
FROM         ICR INNER JOIN
             FinanceDonnee ON Machine.Machine_ID = FinanceDonnee.FinanceDonnee_Machine_ID
GROUP BY ICR_ID, FinanceDonnee.FinanceDonnee_isLocked
```

But It's not working well because it duplicate the Machine_ID, one for locked and the other one for unlocked:

```
ID          Locked   Unlocked
4D9646EC    0        2
4D9646EC    12       0
```

I would like to have this view:

```
ID          Locked   Unlocked
4D9646EC    12       2
```

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply do a sum on locked,unlocked as so:

```
select sum(locked) as Locked ,sum(unlocked) as Unlocked, ID 
from tablea 
inner join tableb on tablea.ID=tableb.ID 
group by ID
```

Using your sql, I think this should work:

```
SELECT machine_id    AS id,
       SUM(locked)   AS locked,
       SUM(unlocked) AS unlocked
FROM   (SELECT machine.machine_id,
               SUM(financedonnee.couthoraire) AS total,
               CASE
                 WHEN financedonnee_islocked = 1 THEN SUM(
                 financedonnee.couthoraire)
                 ELSE 0
               END                            AS locked,
               CASE
                 WHEN financedonnee_islocked = 0 THEN SUM(
                 financedonnee.couthoraire)
                 ELSE 0
               END                            AS unlocked
        FROM   icr
               INNER JOIN financedonnee
                 ON machine.machine_id = financedonnee.financedonnee_machine_id
        GROUP  BY icr_id,
                  financedonnee.financedonnee_islocked) t
GROUP  BY t.machine_id
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked! I did like you suggested, the only modification I did was to put the sub query into a View.